# RESTful CAC authentication

Tags: rest, cas, cac

Ok, I was able to figure out [how to enable RESTful CAS authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625368/working-java-rest-client-example-to-access-cas-rest-api)

Now, I want to be able to enable RESTful CAC login via CAS. I was able to get CAC working with CAS by following this [guide](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/X.509+Certificates).

Anyone tried this before?